# I have to solve for dV which is the volume of a sphere that would be used to "construct" the earth

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The Earth does not have uniform density; it is most dense at its centre and least dense at its surface. The simplest density function is liner; in particular

p(r) = A - Br ;

Where A and B are constants to be determined in this question, and r is the Earth's radius:

6.4 x 10^6 m

Imagine "constructing" the Earth by adding progressively larger concentric spherical shells. The mass of the Earth is then the sum of the masses of the concentric shells.

Since the volume of a sphere whose radius is r is 4/3 pi r^3, the volume (dV) of  a shell whose thickness is *dr* can be found from the derivative *dV/dr*

Solve for *dV*

I have no idea how to go about this question. Any help on solving it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively speaking, the volume of a thin shell around a sphere is the area of the sphere times the thickness of the shell, so $dV=4\pi r^2 dr$

More formally, you have $V=\frac 43 \pi r^3$, now just take $\frac {dV}{dr}$